# How do I remove 'A' in using \cref{} for referring to subsections in Appendix?

Tags: cleveref, appendix, cref

I wonder how can I remove 'A' in using \cref{} for referring to subsections in Appendix?

I have the following pseudo code.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtaes}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[2] \cref{app:subsec2}.

\appendix
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{app:subsec1}

\subsection{Another subsection title}
\label{app:subsec2}
\end{document}
```

For my case, the output of "\cref{app:subsec2}" is "Appendix A-B"

I want the output to be "Appendix B".

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to the `IEEEtaes` class you have used.